# Why does this piece of code cause a segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, as the title suggests I need help with a piece of code I wrote, which is causing a segmentation fault error, here's the code:

```
vector* reads_file(char* name)
{
    vector *vec = vector_new(); //creates a new vector with capacity = 0, size = 0 and elements = NULL
    char *str_aux;
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");


    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        return NULL;
    }


    while(fgets(str_aux, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL){
        if(vextor_inserts(vec, str_aux, -1) == -1)
            return NULL;
        free(str_aux);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return vec;
}
```

and:

```
int vector_inserts(vector* vec, const char* value, int pos)
{
    int i, n;

    if(vec == NULL || pos < -1 || pos > vec->size)
        return -1;

    /* increases vector's elements if there's not enough capacity */
    if(vec->size == vec->capacity)
    {
        if(vec->capacity == 0)
        vec->capacity = 1;
        else
        vec->capacity *= 2;

        vec->elements = (v_element*)realloc(vec->elements, vec->capacity * sizeof(v_element));
        if(vec->elements == NULL)
        return -1;
    }

    /* if pos=-1 inserts in the end of the vector */
    if(pos == -1)
        pos = vec->size;

    /* copies every element from the pos position till the end of the vector to pos+1 */
    for(i=vec->size-1; i>=pos; i--)
    {
        vec->elements[i+1] = vec->elements[i];
    }

    /* allocates space for the new string on position pos */
    vec->elements[pos].str = (char*)calloc(strlen(value)+1, sizeof(char));
    if(vec->elements[pos].str == NULL)
    return -1;

    /* copies value */
    strcpy(vec->elements[pos].str, value);

    vec->size++;

    return pos;
}
```

and whose structures are:

```
typedef struct
{
  char *str;

} v_element;

typedef struct
{
  /** total number of the vector's elements */
  int size;

  /** vector's capacity */
  int capacity;

  /** array of stored elements */
  v_element* elements;

} vector;
```

oh and

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE  256
```

it compiles just right (when using another piece of code that has a main function that calls the reads_file(...) function) but while executing it, it occurs a segmentation fault during the call of the vector_inserts(...) function, but why does this happen? I can't figure it out. It also seems to me that no pointer is wrongly called.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: vector_new(); ?

Comment: `fgets(str_aux, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)` : `str_aux` doesn't initialize.

Comment: how so? or, better, why doesn't it?

Comment: Have you looked at it in a debugger?  Since all the code necessary isn't in your question, we can't. `vextor_inserts` looks like a typo, and `str_aux` is freed but never malloced. Even if it was malloced and you freed it inside the while loop you'd be accessing bad memory the next loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the necessary code is there.
The first thing the main function does is calling the reads_file function, then I created a library, but the problem isn't in there.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `str_aux` given to `fgets()`?

Comment: The segmentation fault also happens if I don't free the memory

Comment: @chux, didn't understand the question

Comment: With `fgets(str_aux, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)` , `fgets()` is passed 3 values: `fp` is the result of `fopen(name, "r")`.  `BUFFER_SIZE` is 256.  What value is in `str_aux`, when it is passed to `fgets()`?  `char *str_aux;` declares the existence of `str_aux`, but what value does it have?  Where in code is `str_aux` assigned or initialized?

Comment: Not if you left that free in there.

Comment: yeah I know that

Comment: @YohsxiKanasurma all the necessary code is not there.  You should post a minimal and complete program that anyone so inclined can run immediately and see exactly what you are seeing.  See the guidelines here [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(i=vec->size-1; i>=pos; i--)
    {
        vec->elements[i+1] = vec->elements[i];
    }
```

`vec->size-1` is the index of the last element in the vector.
`vec->elements[i+1]`  is off the end.

Try `for(i=vec->size-2; i>=pos; i--)`

Note:  you really, really, really, really need to run through this code with a debugger to check what exactly is going on, especially with the corner-cases where the capacity needs to be upped/downed and/or first/ast elements are referenced.  obi-wan errors are just so easy...